# Dropdown in ng-repeat is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project wer I need to show Questionnaries and Answer dropdown related to that in ng-repeat.

When I check on dropdown I am calling an API to fetch answer information to show it in dropdown.

when I click on 1st dropdown it opens up properly and show all the data.

[image: 1st dropdown click]

But when I click on second time on any dropdown it wont open up properly.

[image: second time click]

Can anyone help me know what is the issue.

Below is the code for it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="question in questionnaireData track by $index">
<td><span class="" title="{{question.QuestionItem}}">{{question.QuestionItem}}</span></td>
<td>
    <div class="">
        <!--<label for="answers">Select Answer</label>-->
        <select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" class="form-control" ng-click="getAnswersDetails(question)">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option ng-repeat="answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId]" value="{{answer.MasterData}}">{{answer.MasterData}}</option>
        </select> 
        <input ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" type="text" name="question.QuestionId" class="form-control">
        <!--<span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && formVHD.$valid"></span>-->
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a Plunker or similar that presents the issue? Also, you could consider using [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Dropdown list its better to use ng-option then ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-option="x.data for x in myItems"> 
</select>
```

Because the ng-repeat directive repeats a block of HTML code for each item in an array, it can be used to create options in a dropdown list, but the ng-options directive was made especially for filling a dropdown list with options, and has at least one important advantage:

Dropdowns made with ng-options allows the selected value to be an object, while dropdowns made from ng-repeat has to be a string.

Also You have used same ng-model, id for select and input type text I don't think that's a good idea

```
<input ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" type="text" name="question.QuestionId" class="form-control">

<select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" class="form-control" ng-click="getAnswersDetails(question)">
```

In your case your select should look like this and you should use ng-change instead of ng-click.

```
<select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" class="form-control" ng-change="getAnswersDetails(question)" ng-option="answer.MasterData for answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId]">
        <option selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with you code its not working. not getting dropdown values.

Comment: See I need to call an API on dropdown click so that I can get Values in select box so I have kept ng-click other than that I have replicated all ur select code. but values are not coming in select option.

Comment: [ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) refer this link for more info

Comment: You will have to adjust ng-option as per your need. I gave you the basic idea how to use it. Its difficult to give you working example as I don't know the format of answerData. Refer the link I shared to you in above comment